# How to remove attributes which are added through "->addAttributeToFilter()" from a collection in Magento

Tags: magento

Consider the below code:

```
$productCollection123 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('color',5);
```

so the resultant count is `count($productCollection123) = 57`, now is it possible to do a `removeAttributeFromFilter` so that it removes the condition `'color'=5` from the current collection result?

**Note:** it should not remove condition `'type_id'='simple'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik standard Magento does not have any methods to explicitely remove filters (besides `clear()`, which resets all filters and unloads the collection).

And to be honest, it does not make much sense to remove filters after a collection already has been loaded. At least to me.

The only thing coming to my mind would be to build a collection having the minimum filters (your 2nd one), then `clone` it and extend the clone with the maximum filters (your 1st one).

This would save you some code lines, but lacks readability/maintainability.

Comment: if i clone a collection, will the system do another database call to fill the collection or only keep the data from collection from which its cloned?

Comment: Afaik product collections in Magento do _not_ define any magic `__clone() method, so usage of the PHP `clone` keyword will just create a 1:1 copy of the cloned product. So cloning itself will not produce another query.

Comment: In my case, i have created a clone and then adding fields to filter like below
`$productCollection123 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
  ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore())
  ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))->addAttributeToFilter('color',5);`

and cloning it `$productCollection123Clone = clone $productCollection123;` and adding filter

`$productCollection123Clone->clear()->addAttributeToFilter('pricee',30)->load();`

will this reduce database calls made as compared to intialize a collection and adding attributes to filter each time?

Comment: No, it wouldn't - but that's comparing apples with oranges anyway. The code within your last comment will produce 1 query and load 1 collection. Initializing two collections and adding filters to them will produce 0 queries and load 0 collections, due to Magento's lazy loading. The first real access to the collection's data (using `load()`, `foreach()`, `count()`, etc.) will trigger lazy loading and produce 1 query per collection. To save queries, you could query only one (the bigger) collection. Then do your further filtering within memory only.

Comment: how do i do it? do i have to do like `$productCollection123 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection() ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()) ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))` first load this collection and add filters to it?

Answer (score 3):

No, you have to construct a new query. Once you hit the DB with a query with conditions, you can't just remove a condition and have new data, you have to construct a new query.